# Correctly aligning equations on different lines

Tags: equations, alignment

I am sorry to ask such a basic question, but I haven't found a satisfactory answer in my search (if there is indeed one).

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Where \texttt{aligned} fails me
\fbox{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
    \[\begin{aligned}
        A+B &= C + D\\
            &= C \\
            &= C + E+F \\
            &= C \\
      \end{aligned}\]
  \end{minipage}}

\vskip 1cm
Desired output \fbox{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
    \[\begin{aligned}
        &A+B = C + D\\
        &\hskip 0.3cm = C \\ % The equal sign is again aligned
        &\hskip 0.3cm = C + E+F \\  % Should be right aligned
        &\hskip 0.3cm = G \\  % The equal sign is again aligned
      \end{aligned}\]
  \end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

In other words, I typically want the equal signs to align if there's space. If there's not (like the example above), then I want to choose one line (in this case the longest `= C+E+F`) and make it right aligned, then make all equal signs aligned to the one on the right aligned line.

In my "solution" above, I had to resort to specifying `hskip` to achieve this result, but I am wondering if there's a way to do this automatically without me having to guess the correct spacing.

Comment: Not that it solves your problem, but in this case it is more common to move the `+F` down to its own line and move it slightly right. That will also keep the alignment on all equal signs.

Comment: You can replace \hspace{0.3cm) with \phantom{A+B}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not fully automatic: but saves you the time of guesstimating the required offset: use two layers of `align`.

```
Using \texttt{align}\fbox{ 
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
          \begin{align*}
                A+B = C + D\\
                  \begin{aligned}
        &= C \\ % The equal sign is again aligned
                 &= C + E+F \\  % Should be right aligned
        &= G \\  % The equal sign is again aligned
                  \end{aligned}\end{align*}
  \end{minipage}}
```

(The outer `align` has no `&` signs, and so sets both lines right-aligned. This means that the end of the first line is matched up with the end of the longest line in the inner `aligned`. The inner `aligned` has no terms before the `&` signs, so sets everything in it left-aligned.)

[image]

Comment: Not the solution I wanted, but exactly the solution I need :))

Answer (score 4):

Do this automatically? Hm, this require  quite complex code in which you should:

1. measure width of your equations set in which ampersands are at equal signs,
2. calculate difference between available space and width of equations set,
3. if difference is negative, convert it to offset (from left border) for equations after the first one.
4. write alternative form of equations set. In this is handy to use `mathtools` package and its macro `\MoveEqLeft[<offset>]`, where `<offset>` is given in `em` units (see example below).

So I limit myself to describe algorithm, how to do this. And show a way, how to do this manually on much simpler way:

- At the first compilation estimate the size (in `em`) of the maximal equation protrusion on the right side.
- Than set `<offset>` in \MoveEqLeft` accordingly to your estimation.
- The second compilation should give desired result. If not, accordingly correct size od `<offset>` and repeat compilation.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
Desired output

\fbox{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
    \[\begin{aligned}
    \MoveEqLeft[1.5]
A + B = C + D       \\   
    & = C           \\
    & = C + E + F   \\
    & = G
      \end{aligned}
    \]
  \end{minipage}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's certainly a better solution than the one I was using. Is there maybe a way for commands align lines containing an `&` but left-,right- or center- aligns all other lines not containing `&`?

Comment: @Tohiko, no. Environment `align`, `aligned`, etc. align math term right at left side of ampersand and left on the right side  (as far as I know).